# Would a person standing on the top tube damage a carbon fibre road bike?

Tags: road-bike, carbon

I was riding my aluminium bike and I met some people who had been trapped in a locked park, so I helped them escape by holding the bike against the fence and letting them stand on the top tube to climb out.

If I had had a carbon fibre bike instead how much risk would there have been of serious damage to the bike? I understand that carbon components are engineered to be strong in certain directions and relatively weak in others.

Comment: I would say that there's a danger on any lightweight bike.  The center of the tube is its weakest point.

Comment: On an alloy bike you'd probably be OK standing on the top tube under the saddle, but it would still be better to stand on the saddle itself.  Carbon is too fragile for anything out of the ordinary especially given how sensitive it is to cumulative damage.

Comment: Striking the top tube in a fall is not something you want to do but that is a stress you would expect a bike to take.  I have and not hurt my bikes (cf, aluminum, or steel) in falls like that.  Consider the falls you see on jump, downhill, and street.  I stand on my CF in a park where I CX train to stash my coat in a tree all the time.

Comment: I'd be as concerned as much about the stress on the carbon joints (I think they are bonded by epoxy resin) as the tubes themselves.

Comment: @PeteH A good CF is frame is layed out in one contiguous mold.  A company like Niner has 5 year warranty on carbon fiber - even raced.

Comment: @Blam a Trek Madone frame is made of 7 pieces, which are moulded individually then glued together. However it is far too simplistic to think of these pieces as "tubes" in the steel sense. So it depends what you mean by "good" I suppose - I suspect there are several different manufacturing techniques going on, there's some really interesting stuff on the web about this, the Op should probably google this if he's sufficiently interested to ask questions on here.

Comment: @PeteH Cool I don't mean to argue.  There is a lot of variance in CF and you have big names putting solid warranties on CF.  I guess I will try an answer.  CF just seems to get sensitive.

Comment: There are now two answers that essentially say "Yes, there's a substantial risk of that", and two that say "No, it should be fine on a good bike". I wonder if there's anything published that might help answer this more definitively. Maybe specifications of widely sold bikes that show whether they are designed for this load or not or reports about damaged frames.

Comment: A lot depends on the style of bike.  Blam's bike is a heavily-built off-road bike, others have lightweight racing bikes.  You can't compare them.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Heavy-built?  That IS a light weight race bike.   RDO - Race Day Optimized.

Comment: How much more credible source do you need than a picture and manufacturer with a 5 year warranty?  That is me standing on a $2000 race frame.

Comment: Does the answer change if they were cute?  And single?

Comment: The picture doesn't show a level of risk, and I don't know if the warranty includes this use or not. It's also a mountain bike - the question is about road bikes.

Comment: @bdsl Cool. Well it took the risk at least once.  Actually that is the bike I ride to the park to train  and have stood on it at least 50 times stashing my gear in a tree.  If you think a road frame is somehow  different then it is your question and your bounty.  Did not mean any negative by my question.  Do you  know a single manufacturer that has lower level warranty on CF frame compared to aluminum?  You down voted my answer?

Comment: I don't know whether road frames are significantly different in this regard or not. I'm not sure of the details of any bike warranty. I don't think I've voted any answer up or down on this question.

Comment: @bdsl Cool,  I hope you get the information you are looking for.   Frame  stress are not significantly different.   It is more about characteristics.

Comment: I think you've got the best answers possible already. It depends so much on the fine print that a definitive answer isn't possible. I'm pretty confident that I could compromise or break any lightweight frame by standing on the top tube, but I could also avoid damaging almost any of them doing the same. Even a BSO would likely fail if I was jumping up and down on it while wearing ice skates...

Answer (score 7):

At the risk of getting beat up on carbon will give it a try. 
CF seems to be a sensitive subject.

I don't agree with your assertion CF are engineered to be strong in certain directions and relatively weak in others.  They are designed to have different flex in certain directions - not weak.

If I had 4 bikes I need to use as step stools I would go with this order (and I really have all but aluminum):
1) steel
2) titanium
3) carbon fiber (CF)
4) aluminum

There is a bit of discussion and comments that bearing weight on the top tube is not a stress a bicycle is designed for (and weak).  That is a stress a bike must handle.  If I take a tube and hold it at both ends and try and bend it that is the same type of stress as if I took the tube and put either ends on rocks and pushed on the middle.  The primary force a top tube takes is bending from the ends.  If you watch the video you can see top tube bend and when it fails the two pieces are bending displacement.
[Santa Cruz Bicycles - Test Lab](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/santa-cruz-bicycles-test-lab.html)
And you can see the CF held up pretty nicely.

CF takes criticism as it fails brittlely which is true but it takes a lot to get it to fail.

I would not want to ride any bike that would fail with my weight on the top tube as that is a scenario (crash or drop off) I expect and need it to not fail.

With that said there is not one CF.  A lot of variance in the construction / layout. 
If you are going to ride a CF then buy a good one.

I don't mean to advertise a brand but Niner has 5 year [warranty](http://www.ninerbikes.com/ninercarbon) including racing. 
I have crashed my Niner Air 9 Carbon hard and not even thought twice about the bike.
I use it for CX training at a local park and stand on the top tube to stash my jacket in a tree.

There is stuff CF is not good at. 
Don't put a rack on a CF.
Don't take a [hammer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QNRpSkTGoA) or bat or hard object to CF. 
Don't take a drill to CF. 
Don't over or under torque bolts.

I am just amazed at the slow acceptance of CF frames. 
When CF forks first came out there was a lot a questioning. 
But now CF is the dominant rigid fork. 
A fork takes a lot of stress from a lot of directions. 
People think CF is too light to be strong.

I get engineers are misunderstood (and certainly under appreciated) but a simple one foot drop landing on the front wheel is going to put more stress on a top tube than your weight. The frame did not even flex in the picture.  I would not ride a frame I could not jump on.
[image]

Comment: Steel for the win!

Comment: That's worth a thousand words.  I could probably stand to take that same picture on my carbon Stumpjumper, but I still wouldn't try it with my Tarmac.

Comment: @ChrisinAK https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhabgvIIXik

Comment: @Blam and that is a CF Colnago C59 Disc bike in the video.

Comment: @bdsl So, that is bike taking 6' drops.  And that is a Niner in my picture?  Do you have any evidence a cheaper bike will not take the riders weight on the top tube?

Comment: @Blam All the the forces applied in those videos were just heavier loads of the normal forces that modern tubular frames were designed to support.  Directionality of forces matters greatly when talking about the load bearing properties of any shape.

Comment: @Blam I was agreeing with you that the video is relevant. I wasn't sure until I checked whether it was CF.

Comment: @ChrisinAK Really a drop is not the same "directionality" as weight on the top tube?  It is and directionality is not a stress.  Lets just leave as we don't agree.

Comment: @Blam No, it's not at all.  A drop places force upwards against the axles.  The fork and the seat stays transmit that force to each end of the top tube.  In a "drop" the top tube is being compressed from each end.  It's much different than placing all the force against the middle of the tube.  It's very similar to how a person standing on my shoulders would be tolerable, but a person standing on the center of my spine would not.

Comment: @ChrisinAK I have degree in engineering that says no.  And if a top tube was designed for compression it would be straight and uniform thickness like the columns in a building.  I would rather have person stand on my spine - it feels good.  For the second time leave as we don't agree.

Comment: @ChrisinAK: I agree and I’d also like to point out that tubes in lightweight bicycles tend to be made with great diameters and thin walls. So simply standing on the tube could put a dent in it.

Comment: @Michael Standing on that bike dented nothing.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QNRpSkTGoA

Answer (score 5):

You could theoretically damage any frame in that manner.  Tubes are meant to support a load from either end, not in the middle.  No bike is designed to support a great deal of weight on the top tube.  Theoretically carbon, steel and titanium could all flex/bend and resume their normal shape, where aluminum couldn't, but nonetheless it still isn't a good idea with any of them.

There is so much variation in material you could easily make a thick walled carbon frame that would stand up to such abuse or a paper thin steel frame that would bend and fail instantly.  You are correct that carbon can be designed to be stronger in some directions that others, but it's still being shaped into a tube (or some variation of) that design and has it's own inherent strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: Yes, a BSO from Wally World will probably support more weight on its top tube than any sort of fancy bike.  In your traditional diamond frame there is very little "bending moment" on the tubes -- it's all tension/compression -- and the tubes do not need to be made to greatly resist bending.  In the name of lightness the tubes of better quality bikes are made as thin as practical, and, eg, steel bikes generally have "double butted" tubes that have thinner walls in the middle than on the ends.

Comment: @Blam I can compress the top ovalized tube of my Specialized Tarmac with my hand (noticable flex from top to bottom).  I have trusted that bike to some pretty hairy descents and cobblestone roads.  I would never stand on the top tube.  I would certainly never let a stranger stand on it.  I am certain most people's weight would generate more force than I can generate with my hand.

Comment: @ChrisinAK Cool. Flex and fail are not the same.  I would not ride a bike that could not take like 4x my static weight.  +1 don't mean any disrespect.  What you don't get is that stress from either end is stress in the middle.

Comment: @Blam - It's true that in an crash an substantial amount of force might be applied laterally to the top tube.  And it's not terribly unusual for bike frames (especially lightweight bikes) to be damaged in crashes.  In ordinary operation, though, there is nothing present that would apply such lateral force.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I have crashed bikes hard and not damaged them. A simple simple 2 foot drop puts more stress on a top tube than my static weight and I consider that an ordinary operation.

Comment: @Blam None felt.  It's highly likely the Tarmac could withstand those forces, I still wouldn't try it.  The direction of the stresses does matter greatly, however.  Squeezing an egg end to end and then sideways is the easy eggsample.

Comment: @Blam - A "simple 2 foot drop" does not put any significant *bending force* on the tube.  It's all compression/twisting.  A pipe (any pipe) is very strong in compression, tension, or torsion, but very much weaker when force is applied laterally to the middle.

Comment: You will notice that they're not testing diamond frames.  And, in real life, I've seen seen several bikes damaged by twist -- the fact that they didn't test for it is irrelevant (or perhaps deceptive).

Comment: @DanielRHicks Link deleted so here it is http://www.pinkbike.com/news/santa-cruz-bicycles-test-lab.html  Yes I noticed they are not testing diamond frames - I would expect Santa Cruz to test their own frames.  So you have seen bike damaged by twist.  You said a simple drop does not put any significant bending force on the tube and that video shows that is wrong.

Comment: The videos show that if the tube is not straight it loses considerable integrity in compression.  This is no surprise to an engineer.  The "bending" that occurs is due to the "poor" design of the frame (from the standpoint of structural engineering principles), and it occurs when the top member is in reasonably pure compression, with no significant bending moment applied.

Answer (score 2):

Bicycle frames are lightweight structures that have great strength when supporting the loads that the road imparts. Normally the top tube would experience compression or tension due to the weight of the rider. It also needs torsional stiffness to keep the bike stable. It is not designed to take the bending moment of a persons weight in the center. Aluminum bikes tend to have large diameter tubes for torsional stiffness and this gives them bending stiffness as well. Localized buckling of a thin wall is also likely.

Carbon fiber frames are not light because the material has magic properties. Carbon fiber has great axial strength it is true but much of the lightness of the frame is due to the finite element models that help designers put material exactly where it will do the most good. Before I would let anyone use my $3000 frame for a stepladder, I would think seriously about that.

Answer (score 1):

I would not be afraid to let anybody stand on my carbon fiber, aluminum, or steel bike. If standing on the top tube breaks the bike, it would be liable to break after any minor mishap, and you're safer getting it repaired or replaced. Bikes are sturdy -- even CF road bikes.